# Is there a way to destroy a class instance or destroy GLcontext in it on a react.FC State(new "class object with THREE.js in it") to avoid memory leak

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, three.js, webgl

I have a working react.FC() app.

You can trhowBottle in the metaverse(as a bottle in the sea) to be open in the future.

The app then  retrieve information on the API and construct a component(maping of array with all bottles) that will include an instance of a class("SideBottleScene.ts"With THREE.JS model, rendrere...scene...etc.) for each bottles. So when the list shows, there is a 3JS bottle appearing for each entrys plus all infos. The instance of SideBottleScene is created in a useEffect[] in a SideBottle component. there is a SideBottle for each bottle and this works good but with memory leaks because the SideBottleScene stays in memory when change route...When I come back to Bottles route it recreates new SideBottleScene for each bottles....and it work...but the old SideBottleScene are still in memory.

```
const SideBottle: React.FC<IProps> = ({ bottle, loaders }) => {
  const [sideBottleScene, setSideBottleScene] = useState<SideBottleScene>();
  const [bottleState] = useState<bottle>(bottle);

  const refCanvasThree = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const refDivCanvasThree = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const refWideSizeBottle = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Démmarage du Siedbottle

    setSideBottleScene(
      new SideBottleScene(
        refCanvasThree.current as HTMLCanvasElement,
        refDivCanvasThree.current as HTMLDivElement,
        refWideSizeBottle.current as HTMLDivElement,
        bottleState,
        loaders
      )
    );

    return () => {
      console.log("destroying"); //This is triggered

      //destroy all 3Dmodel, context and renderer
      //But is not completed here when I change routes
      //It does wotk if I bt it on a KEYDOWN listener
      sideBottleScene?.destroy(); //NOT TRIGGERED and I tried with an await function

      // setSideBottleScene(null); //Don't work.
    };
  }, []);
```

When I change routes, the class(SideBottleScene) including renderer, Scene and all GL stuff..is not destroy so it stays in memory and create a memory leak.

For exemple if I put a keydown listener in the SideBottleScene.ts...even after changing routes, I can console.log() all attributes of the class that should be gone. So when I come back to the the bottles Routes, instead of recreating only new bottles...it recreates new bottles but all old bottles are still in memorys...but not showing to screen...but they exist in memory.

Example : I Go to see the bottles componment....there is 3 bottles...I push a key(listener in SideBottleScene) ...it console.logs all attribute for 3 bottles...I go on a different routes...I come back to bottles route and see the 3 bottles again(3 bottles in DB)....but if I push a key...it console.log 6 bottles...and then 9...12..15... until THREE says..Warning to many context...older one will be lost...

Here is the instanciated class....one for each bottles of the Database retrieved.

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { CubeTexture, Mesh } from "three";
import { setupGlftModel } from "../helper/TalkToUser";
import { TextGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js";
import { Font } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader";
import { bottle } from "../../types/bottleType";
import { UniqueLoaders } from "./UniqueLoaders";
import gsap from "gsap";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

export class SideBottleScene {
  canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
  divXpand: HTMLDivElement;
  isBottleExpand: boolean;
  scene: THREE.Scene;
  camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  renderWidth: number;
  renderHeight: number;
  width: number;
  height: number;
  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  // ambiantLight: THREE.AmbientLight;

  fullScreenMode: boolean;

  //lights
  spotLight: THREE.SpotLight;
  hemiLight: THREE.HemisphereLight;
  dirLight: THREE.DirectionalLight;

  //cubemap
  cubeMapLoader: THREE.CubeTextureLoader;
  cubeMap: CubeTexture;
  skyBox: Mesh;
  cubeShader: THREE.Shader;
  skyBoxMaterial: THREE.ShaderMaterial;

  //loader
  loaders: UniqueLoaders;

  orbitControl: OrbitControls;

  bottle: bottle;

  //glft Bottle
  bottleModel: THREE.Mesh;
  bottleModelMateriel: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial;
  sphereColorTexture: THREE.Texture;

  //text 3d
  colorTextTitle: THREE.Texture;
  materialtxt: THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial;
  titleFont: Font;
  textGeoTitle: TextGeometry | any;
  meshTextTitle: THREE.Mesh;

  constructor(
    canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
    divCanvas: HTMLDivElement,
    divWideBottle: HTMLDivElement,
    bottle: bottle,
    loaders: UniqueLoaders
  ) {
    this.renderWidth = divCanvas.offsetWidth;
    this.renderHeight = divCanvas.offsetHeight;
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, this.renderWidth / this.renderHeight, 1, 5000);
    this.canvas = canvas;

    this.bottle = bottle;

    this.divXpand = divWideBottle;
    this.isBottleExpand = false;
    this.width = divCanvas.offsetWidth / 4;
    this.height = divCanvas.offsetHeight / 4;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas, antialias: true, alpha: true });

    this.fullScreenMode = false;

    this.camera.position.set(0, 0, 400);

    this.renderer.setSize(this.renderWidth, this.renderHeight);
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.loaders = loaders;

    this.hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
    this.hemiLight.position.set(0, 200, 0);
    this.scene.add(this.hemiLight);

    this.dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
    this.dirLight.position.set(75, 200, -75);
    this.scene.add(this.dirLight);

    this.spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1);
    this.spotLight.castShadow = true;
    this.spotLight.position.set(0, 0, 200);
    this.scene.add(this.spotLight);

    //cubemap
    this.cubeMapLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
    this.cubeMap = new CubeTexture();
    this.skyBox = new Mesh();
    this.cubeShader = THREE.ShaderLib.cube;
    this.skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();

    //glft bottle
    this.bottleModel = new THREE.Mesh();
    this.bottleModelMateriel = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial();

    const rndtexture = this.bottle.scene.texture;
    this.sphereColorTexture = this.loaders.textureLoaderTextTitle.load(
      `/textures/bottle/color${rndtexture}.jpg`
    );
    this.loadCubeMap();
    this.loadBottle();

    //textBottle
    this.colorTextTitle = new THREE.Texture();
    this.materialtxt = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial();
    this.titleFont = new Font({});
    this.load_txt_fonts();
    this.textGeoTitle = {};
    this.meshTextTitle = new Mesh();

    //event handler
    this.listenerHandling(divCanvas);

    this.orbitControl = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
  }

  tick = () => {
    this.loaders.elapsedTime = this.loaders.clock.getElapsedTime() as number;
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.tick);
    this.bottleModel.rotation.y = -this.loaders.elapsedTime;
    // this.skyBox.rotation.z = this.loaders.elapsedTime / 5;

    this.orbitControl.update();
    // this.bottleModel.rotation.x = Math.sin(-this.loaders.elapsedTime);
  };

  async resizeRendererOnChangeDivCanvas() {}

  async listenerHandling(divCanvas: HTMLDivElement) {
    //Resize window function
    let camAdjust = 0;
    let OldOffsetWidht = divCanvas.offsetWidth;
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
      // Update sizes
      this.renderWidth = divCanvas.offsetWidth;
      this.renderHeight = divCanvas.offsetHeight;

      // Update camera on resize
      camAdjust = divCanvas.offsetWidth - OldOffsetWidht;
      this.camera.position.z = this.camera.position.z - camAdjust;
      this.camera.aspect = this.renderWidth / this.renderHeight;
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      OldOffsetWidht = divCanvas.offsetWidth;

      this.orbitControl.update();

      // Update renderer
      if (!this.fullScreenMode) {
        this.renderer.setSize(this.renderWidth, this.renderHeight);
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
      }
    });

    this.canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", () => {
      if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
        this.fullScreenMode = true;
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.canvas.requestFullscreen();
        this.orbitControl.update();
      } else {
        document.exitFullscreen();
        this.fullScreenMode = false;
        this.renderer.setSize(this.renderWidth, this.renderHeight);
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        this.orbitControl.update();
      }
    });


    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      gsap.to(this.camera.position, { duration: 0.5, delay: 0, z: this.camera.position.z - 150 });
      gsap.to(this.bottleModel.rotation, { duration: 0.5, delay: 0, z: 0.3 });
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      this.orbitControl.update();
    });
    this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      gsap.to(this.camera.position, { duration: 0.5, delay: 0, z: this.camera.position.z + 150 });
      gsap.to(this.bottleModel.rotation, { duration: 0.5, delay: 0, z: 0 });
      this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      this.orbitControl.update();
    });

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (keydown) => {
      this.destroy();
      // this.destroy();
    });

    // this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    // this.orbitControl.update();
  }

  load_txt_fonts() {
    this.colorTextTitle = this.loaders.textureLoaderTextTitle.load("/textures/color.png");
    this.materialtxt.map = this.colorTextTitle;
    this.materialtxt.metalness = 0.7;
    this.materialtxt.roughness = 0.5;
    this.loaders.fontLoader.load("/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json", (font: Font) => {
      this.titleFont = font;
      this.showTitle();
    });
  }

  loadCubeMap() {
    const cubeToLoad = this.bottle.scene.skybox;
    this.cubeMap = this.loaders.CubeTextureLoader.load([
      `/textures/environmentMaps/${cubeToLoad}/px.jpg`,
      `/textures/environmentMaps/${cubeToLoad}/nx.jpg`,
      `/textures/environmentMaps/${cubeToLoad}/py.jpg`,
      `/textures/environmentMaps/${cubeToLoad}/ny.jpg`,
      `/textures/environmentMaps/${cubeToLoad}/pz.jpg`,
      `/textures/environmentMaps/${cubeToLoad}/nz.jpg`
    ]);
    // this.scene.background = this.cubeMap; //version facile mais sans contorle alpha et tout.
    this.cubeShader.uniforms.tCube.value = this.cubeMap;
    this.cubeShader.uniforms.opacity.value = this.bottle.scene.skyOpacity; // semi-transparent skybox

    this.skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      fragmentShader: this.cubeShader.fragmentShader,
      vertexShader: this.cubeShader.vertexShader,
      uniforms: this.cubeShader.uniforms,
      side: THREE.BackSide,
      transparent: true
    });

    this.skyBox = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(10000, 10000, 10000), this.skyBoxMaterial);
    this.scene.add(this.skyBox);
  }

  async loadBottle() {
    this.bottleModel = setupGlftModel(
      await this.loaders.glftLoader.loadAsync("/model/bottle/bottle.glb")
    );
    this.bottleModel.position.setY(-60);
    this.bottleModel.scale.set(
      this.bottle.scene.scaleBottleX * this.bottleModel.scale.x,
      this.bottle.scene.scaleBottleY * this.bottleModel.scale.y,
      this.bottle.scene.scaleBottleZ * this.bottleModel.scale.z
    );

    this.bottleModelMateriel.metalness = this.bottle.scene.metalness;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.roughness = this.bottle.scene.roughness;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.envMap = this.cubeMap;
    // this.bottleModelMateriel.displacementScale = 15;
    // this.bottleModelMateriel.displacementMap = this.sphereHeightTexture;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.map = this.sphereColorTexture;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.opacity = this.bottle.scene.opacity;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.transparent = true;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.needsUpdate = true;
    this.bottleModelMateriel.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    // this.bottleModelMateriel.alphaMap = this.sphereAlphaTexture;

    this.bottleModel.material = this.bottleModelMateriel;
    this.scene.add(this.bottleModel);
  }

  showTitle() {
    this.textGeoTitle = new TextGeometry(this.bottle.title || "", {
      font: this.titleFont,
      size: 8,
      height: 1,
      curveSegments: 20,
      bevelEnabled: true,
      bevelThickness: 1,
      bevelSize: 0,
      bevelOffset: 0,
      bevelSegments: 0
    });
    this.textGeoTitle.center();
    this.meshTextTitle = new THREE.Mesh(this.textGeoTitle, this.materialtxt);
    this.meshTextTitle.position.z = 100;
    this.meshTextTitle.position.y = 35;
    // textMeshTitle.rotateY(-0.3);
    this.scene.add(this.meshTextTitle);
  }
  destructor() {
    // This function is called when the object is destroyed
    this.scene.traverse((o: any) => {
      if (o.geometry) {
        o.geometry.dispose();
        // console.log("dispose geometry ", o.geometry)
      }
      if (o.texture) {
        o.texture.dispose();
        // console.log("dispose geometry ", o.geometry)
      }
      if (o.material) {
        if (o.material.length) {
          for (let i = 0; i < o.material.length; ++i) {
            o.material[i].dispose();
            // console.log("dispose material ", o.material[i])
          }
        } else {
          o.material.dispose();
          // console.log("dispose material ", o.material)
        }
      }
    });

    this.renderer.dispose();
    this.renderer.forceContextLoss();
    console.log("DESTROYED!");
  }

  destroy = async () => {
    // TRAVERSING ALL OBJECTS IN THE SCENE
    this.scene.traverse((o: any) => {
      if (o.geometry) {
        o.geometry.dispose();
        // console.log("dispose geometry ", o.geometry)
      }
      if (o.texture) {
        o.texture.dispose();
        // console.log("dispose geometry ", o.geometry)
      }
      if (o.material) {
        if (o.material.length) {
          for (let i = 0; i < o.material.length; ++i) {
            o.material[i].dispose();
            // console.log("dispose material ", o.material[i])
          }
        } else {
          o.material.dispose();
          // console.log("dispose material ", o.material)
        }
      }
    });

    this.renderer.dispose();
    this.renderer.forceContextLoss();
    console.log("DESTROYED!");
  };
}
```

I tried to :

Call the destroy method on useEffect destructor:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //Démmarage du Siedbottle

    setSideBottleScene(
      new SideBottleScene(
        refCanvasThree.current as HTMLCanvasElement,
        refDivCanvasThree.current as HTMLDivElement,
        refWideSizeBottle.current as HTMLDivElement,
        bottleState,
        loaders
      )
    );

    return () => {
      console.log("destroying"); //This is triggered

      //destroy all 3Dmodel, context and renderer
      //But is not trigger here when I change routes
      sideBottleScene?.destroy(); //NOT TRIGGERED and I tried with an await function

      // setSideBottleScene(null); //Don't work.
    };
  }, []);
```

It tried to delete attributes of the class or put them = undefined...But with TypeScript...I can't put them to undefined as they are strong typed.

Tried a lot of way to destroy the instance...at least destroy the scene, rendere and model...witch work if I do it on a keydown:

Also tried to put the destroying in Class Destructor.....but its never called...as the class never get collect by the garbage colector.

```
  destroy = async () => {
    // TRAVERSING ALL OBJECTS IN THE SCENE
    this.scene.traverse((o: any) => {
      if (o.geometry) {
        o.geometry.dispose();
        // console.log("dispose geometry ", o.geometry)
      }
      if (o.texture) {
        o.texture.dispose();
        // console.log("dispose geometry ", o.geometry)
      }
      if (o.material) {
        if (o.material.length) {
          for (let i = 0; i < o.material.length; ++i) {
            o.material[i].dispose();
            // console.log("dispose material ", o.material[i])
          }
        } else {
          o.material.dispose();
          // console.log("dispose material ", o.material)
        }
      }
    });

    this.renderer.dispose();
    this.renderer.forceContextLoss();
    console.log("DESTROYED!");
  };
```

But it does not complete when I put that call on de useEffect Destructor...Like it not done...though it wat a async probleme but even it I call a function with an await it does not do it.

Thanks a lot for help !

PS : I know....react three fiber should be better but I don't want to learn that now and I already compose all that SideBottleScene.ts

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `useEffect` cleanup hook is not working because of a stale closure. `sideBottleScene` is `undefined` when the closure is created.

```
sideBottleScene?.destroy(); // this will never be called
```

Instead, assign the new scene to a variable within the function scope, and then call destroy on that variable in the cleanup method.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const sideBottleScene = new SideBottleScene(
    refCanvasThree.current as HTMLCanvasElement,
    refDivCanvasThree.current as HTMLDivElement,
    refWideSizeBottle.current as HTMLDivElement,
    bottleState,
    loaders
  )

  setSideBottleScene(sideBottleScene);

  return () => {
    sideBottleScene.destroy();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Man ! This tottaly did the job now mu DESTOY is called ! So no memory leak !

Thank you so much !

That way....I still have a listerner active for every created class... Is there a way to get rid of ALL the class.. I read that if I cancel all reference the garbage collector will handle that...

But with typeScript...can't to that...

Or is there a way to lose the instance when I switch route.

Comment: @nok I don't understand your question. Can you provide more details?

Comment: In order for your class instances to be garbage collected, you will need to delete all references to the instance, and you will also need to remove the event listeners. JavaScript will not garbage collect the instance until it is unreachable and no active event listeners remain.

Comment: I understand that...But I can I remove all intance in a Strong TypeScript app...Can't put the attribute to undefined cause of typescript. Thanks !